# Ending program after a certain period of time

Tags: python, time

I have to make a program for school which talks to the user about certain things. It is supposed to run for atleast 3 minutes. I want to implement something which stops the program after 3 minutes.

My code doesn't seem to be ending the program after the amount of seconds i specify in *PROGRAM_DURATION*

```
import time

start = time.time()

PROGRAM_DURATION = 180

x = 1
while x == 1:
    if time.time() < start + PROGRAM_DURATION:
        print("Hello")
        chat()
    else:
        print("We're out of time")
        break
```

I have tried removing *chat()* from the code but the program still did not finish after given time

**EDIT:**
This is the exact code copy pasted from my program:
    import time

```
start = time.time()

PROGRAM_DURATION = 5 #set to 5 to check if it works

x = 1
while x == 1:
    if time.time() < start + PROGRAM_DURATION:
        print("greeting")
        print("What is your name")
        name = input()
        print("Hi,",name,"nice to meet you")
        print("Lets talk")
        chat() #function which lets the user chose what the subject will be

    else:
        print("Well,",name,"we have run out of time")
        print("Thanks for talking to me")
        break
```

Comment: `chat()` might be blocking.

Comment: @NehalJWani i tried running the code without 'chat()' and it still didnt run correctly

Comment: As Nehal says, chat() must be the issue - if you replace chat() with a println statement, the program works as expected. Try putting a println after chat() and see if you are actually returning to the loop after chat as you are expecting to. [EDIT]: Can you post exactly what you are running without chat(), as I can't produce your problem.

Comment: @Nick just edited the OP with the code, I just removed the chat() line from the program and tried running it with no effect

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem once `chat()` is removed. The code in the edit works fine for me in Python 2.7, I think the issue is in `chat()`

Comment: @kleanthis I'm afraid if I remove the line with chat(), then the program works. I am using python 3.5

Comment: @Nick yes i think that function is definitely the problem.